# Raw file is not showing up in android studio

Tags: java, android, audio

I'm building a soundboard app using android studio. It was supposed to have my sound in the app where I can click on with the raw file but it gives me this error "cannot resolve symbol for r file". Ill be producing snippets of the code since I have too it to post here

```
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer= R.raw.bearsongbystevezaragozasourcefednerd;
}
```

Comment: Producing snippets of your code? Why not just include the part that is relevant for the actual problem you are facing, instead of posting all of it. Try tracing you error to a specific line and add that code here, along with your full stack trace. Welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//initialize     
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bearsongbystevezaragozasourcefednerd);   
//start playback    
player.start();
```